# what does "Memory index truncation" mean?

Tags: verilog

I'm trying to implement the memory model as below, but I got these warning messages:

```
assign Data = (!CS && !OE) ? Mem[Address] : {WordSize{1'bz}};
                                       |
ncelab: *W,BIGWIX (./sram.v,16|39): Memory index truncation.  
    Mem[Address] = Data;
              |
ncelab: *W,BIGWIX (./sram.v,20|14): Memory index truncation.
```

Here is my code:

```
// RAM Model
//


module sram (Address, Data, CS, WE, OE);

parameter AddressSize = 2592;
parameter WordSize = 32;

input [AddressSize-1:0] Address;
inout [WordSize-1:0] Data;
input CS, WE, OE;

reg [WordSize-1:0] Mem [0:(1<<AddressSize)-1];

assign Data = (!CS && !OE) ? Mem[Address] : {WordSize{1'bz}};

always @(CS or WE)
  if (!CS && !WE)
    Mem[Address] = Data;

always @(WE or OE)
  if (!WE && !OE)
    $display("Operational error in RamChip: OE and WE both active");

endmodule
```

What does "Memory index truncation" mean?

Comment: Are you sure that you need 2592 bits addressing for memory? Because that's a huge amount of memory. For example you can address 1000 petabytes with 64 bits of addressing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get more verbose help on any Cadence Incisive warnings using `nchelp`:

```
nchelp ncelab BIGWIX
ncelab/BIGWIX =
    A memory is being indexed. The index expression has a width
    greater than a machine word, which is typically 32 bits.
    Only 32 bits are used. This truncation may result in
    undesired behavior.
```

As mentioned in the Comment, you probably do not want the Address input signal to be 2592 bits wide or your memory to have (1<<2592) locations.